# Stata- calculating conditional means, subtracting them, dividing the difference

Tags: stata

My dataset is like this.....

```
Pizzas    Hamburgers     Type
10.7      5.6            1 
9.6       6.7            2
13.4      4.1            3
7.2       3.7            4
```

Here is what I need to do (this is essentially calculating a Wald estimator in econometrics, if you are familiar, if not, no biggie)

1. I need to create new categories so that if the observation is type 1 then it is 'first' and if it is 2, 3, or 4, it is 'other'
2. calculate the averages of pizzas and hamburgers by first and other
3. subtract the means between first and other
4. divide the differences

Comment: Some attempt at code is expected here.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be more structure than this to the problem; otherwise it's school arithmetic. This may get you started, but I think you need to show more substance about your data structure and larger goals. In a larger dataset, `collapse` may be a good idea, depending on what you want to do with the results.

```
clear 
input Pizzas    Hamburgers     Type
10.7      5.6            1 
9.6       6.7            2
13.4      4.1            3
7.2       3.7            4
end

gen First = Type == 1 

egen MeanPizzas = mean(Pizzas), by(First) 
egen MeanHamb = mean(Hamb), by(First) 
sort First 
gen DiffMeanPizzas = MeanPizzas[1] - MeanPizzas[_N] 
gen DiffMeanHamb = MeanHamb[1] - MeanHamb[_N] 


tabdisp First, c(Mean* Diff*)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    First |     MeanPizzas        MeanHamb  DiffMeanPizzas    DiffMeanHamb
----------+---------------------------------------------------------------
        0 |       10.06667        4.833333       -.6333332       -.7666669
        1 |           10.7             5.6       -.6333332       -.7666669
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```